# SQL query create duplicate rows?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

DB is successfully connected but i run the code and then in DB there are duplicate rows
Why?

```
public class MySQLTest 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        try {
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
            String sql = "INSERT INTO customer (firstname,lastname) VALUES (?,?)";
            PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setString(1,"Name");
            statement.setString(2, "LastName");
            
            int rows = statement.executeUpdate();
            if (rows > 0 ) {
                System.out.println("A row is inserted");
                
            }
            statement.close();
            con.close();
        }
```

Comment: Probably because you enter the names more than once while testing.

Comment: If you want to stop that, then you will have to make one or both of the columns in the table unique, but then you will have to expect to have to process a duplicate error returned from the database in your Catch block, and decide what to do about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, you using code as test, and you run more then 1 time `without a primary key` in table it's will add multiples records duplicates.

Try add an column `id` as int autoincrement and put both columns `Name` and `LastName` in `UniqueKey`.

This changes will throws exception when run more then time with same values, and you have the use `try/catch` to capture exception.